# Target Specific Category Toolbar M2

Tags: magento2

Due to the way the toolbars are added on the category page view showing products, there is no way to target it specifically.

If you try the layout xml argument it only passes the data to the block, it does not set the class on the toolbar.

I cannot target only one of them with css or php due to the way they are being rendered, how can I get an additional class on only one of the toolbars?

The block and template in question:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
```